# How can I move all classes from a directory under a module?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I have a project with a lot of tests. One issue is that many classes under `tests/integration` and `tests/functional` have colliding class names. This produces errors when trying to run tests inside RubyMine.

To avoid the huge task to rename them one by one, I was thinking to move all classes inside `integration` inside a module, e.g. `IntegrationTests`, end result would be:

```
module IntegrationTests
  class Whatever < Something
    ...
  end
end
```

I see found way to refactor all classes under that directory like that. Any clues? I would also accept answers using another tool if this is impossible with RubyMine itself.

Comment: There's no such a feature in RubyMine but you're welcome to submit a feature request on the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY By the way, which errors do you get while running tests?

Comment: @Olivia, thanks, submitted https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-28190

Comment: @Olivia, I don't have the error message handy but it was something along the lines of "incompatible parent class for ...` because in two files there is the same class name defined but with a different parent class. It went unnoticed because tests are never run locally in bulk but in an CI system where apparently it somehow works, don't know why yet.